# Prove that if $t>2n^2$, then $t!>(n^2)^{t-2n^2}$

Tags: inequality, proof-verification, factorial

How to prove that if $t>2n^2$, then $t!>(n^2)^{t-n^2}$, where t is a positive integer and n is an integer greater than 2 ?

I have:
$t>2n^2$ 
$t(t-1)>(2n^2)(2n^2 -1)$ 
... 
$t! > \Pi_{i=0}^{n-1}(2n^2 -i)$

But then how is it linked to the result I would like to prove ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $t>2n^2$ then
$$\eqalign{t!
  &=t(t-1)(t-2)\cdots(2n^2)(2n^2-1)\cdots(n^2+1)(n^2)\cdots(2)(1)\cr
  &\ge t(t-1)(t-2)\cdots(2n^2)(2n^2-1)\cdots(n^2+1)\cr
  &>(n^2)(n^2)(n^2)\cdots(n^2)(n^2)\cdots(n^2)\cr
  &=(n^2)^{t-n^2}\ .\cr}$$
The reason for the exponent $t-n^2$ is that we started with $t$ factors and we have thrown out $n^2$ of them.

This is the inequality in your question, and the inequality in your title follows easily.

**Comment**.  If $t>n^2$ this still works: $t>2n^2$ is not necessary.  However, if $t>2n^2$ then we can go further:
$$t!>(n^2)^{t-n^2}=n^{2t-2n^2}=n^{t+(t-2n^2)}$$
so
$$t!>n^t\ ,$$
and I suspect that this may be the ultimate aim of your question.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't have the right intuition for the beginning. And indeed the ultimate goal was to prove that $t!>n^t$ but that part was easy once the first part proved. How does the intuition come to you to do so on your first line ?

Comment: As far as I remember it wasn't so much intuition as trial and error.  I might have first tried dropping the last $n$ terms of the factorial, which gives $t!>n^{t-n}$... but this clearly is not going to lead to $t!>n^t$.  Then (just guessing, I don't really remember, it was a long time ago) I might have tried dropping $kn$ terms to get $t!>(kn)^{t-kn}$.  At this point it becomes clear(ish) that we need a multiple of $t$ like $2t$ instead of $t$ in the exponent.  Maybe this is what suggested dropping $n^2$ terms.